# Cannot invoke initializer for type UNNotificationCategory when migrating to iOS10

Tags: ios, notifications, swift2, ios10

I am using an example project to work around new notifications, transition from Swift 2.2 to Swift 2.3, also from iOS 9 to iOS 10. I am using the code below, taken from [this example](http://cleanswifter.com/ios-10-local-notifications/):

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func setupAndGenerateLocalNotification() {
    // Register an Actionable Notification
    let highFiveAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: NotificationActions.HighFive.rawValue, title: "High Five", options: [])

    //next line is an error:
    let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "wassup", actions: [highFiveAction], minimalActions: [highFiveAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [.customDismissAction])
    //Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UNNotificationCategory' with an argument list of type '(identifier: String, actions: _, minimalActions: _, intentIdentifiers: _, options: _)'

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])

    let highFiveContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    highFiveContent.title = "Wassup?"
    highFiveContent.body = "Can I get a high five?"

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)

    let highFiveRequestIdentifier = "sampleRequest"
    let highFiveRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: highFiveRequestIdentifier, content: highFiveContent, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().addNotificationRequest(highFiveRequest) { (error) in
        // handle the error if needed
        print(error)
    }
}
```

The error I get is

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UNNotificationCategory' with an argument list of type '(identifier: String, actions: _, minimalActions: _, intentIdentifiers: _, options: _)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention what your error was, but I suspect the code you copied was written for an earlier beta than you have installed.

I'm using Swift 3 in my work, rather than Swift 2.3. There, as of Xcode 8 beta 5, you should change `UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().addNotificationRequest` to `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add`, and also remove `minimalActions: [highFiveAction],` from your `UNNotificationCategory`. It's possible only the latter might apply in Swift 2.3?

I hope that will get you going, but be warned: this might change again before iOS 10 goes final. In particular, I suspect `current()` might become `current`.

Comment: oh sorry, the error is inside the code (commented out)

Comment: no, I need swift 2.3, and it's exactly the code i'm using (indeed I had to modify swift3 example back to fit to swift 2.3)

Comment: Did you try doing what I said – removing the `minimalActions` parameter?

Comment: yes, indeed this was the case. by the time I am reading this, I have figured this out myself.. thank you!